# Handling exceptions in Vuex mutators

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I came across this scenario today, and would like to know the best approach to handling it.

The Vuex action uses Axios to post a record to the back end, catching any exceptions. Once the POST request returns, a mutator is called with the returned data. The issue is if an exception occurs in the mutator, it is not caught by error handling in the action, or the calling component.

**Example**
If the spread operator within the mutation is removed, an "object expected, got array" exception would be thrown, which I would expect to be caught within the `.catch()` function of the action call within the component, but it is not. Why and how can this be handled? If the solution to wrap the action call in an additional try/catch?

**Action**

```
async saveRecords({ commit }, records) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.post("/records", records)
                .then((res) => {
                    commit('addRecords', res.data.records)
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                })
        })
    }
```

**Mutation**

```
addCase: function (state, caseRecord) {
    console.log("inside mutation")
    state.cases.push(...caseRecord) 
},
```

**Component**

```
this.saveRecords(records)
    .catch((e) => {
          // IExpecting exception from mutation to be caught here
        })
      });
```

Comment: First of all defining the first function as async is redundant, it also looks like that's not even valid (but I'll assume it's pseudo code for now). Returning a promise from an async function probably wraps it again? I need to check that.

What you need to do is catch the error and push a new error state or go back to the initial if thats too hard. I would also suggest using the async/await pattern instead of raw promises since it'll make your code easier to read.

Comment: Here's a good resource I found cached: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JmLRj3N2D6QJ:https://terabytetiger.com/lessons/articles/error-handling-in-vue-with-vuex/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656993/best-practice-in-error-handling-in-vuejs-with-vuex-and-axios Here's another question I found

Comment: Mutations are low-level ops. Since most mutations are supposed to be used inside actions, it makes sense to provide them with verified data and throw an error from an action instead. `new Promise` is known as promise construction antipattern and should be avoided, it's error-prone.